# Extracting year and month from Date in R

Tags: r

So i have a dataframe in R:

```
Date

2002-01-24
2003-02-25
2004-03-26
```

and when i check the data type of the Date column,

```
str(df$Date)
```

it is of **"Date"** type.

Now, i want to create a new column named "Month", which i would take the portion of year and month in the Date column, without the day.

```
Date           Month
2002-01-24     2002-01
2003-02-25     2003-02
2004-03-26     2004-03
```

The way i did it is below:

```
df$Month <- format(as.Date(df$Date), "%Y-%m"))
```

but when i run

```
str(df$Month)
```

it says it is of **"chr"** type instead of **"Date"**. Is there any ways to keep it in the **"Date"** data type instead of being converted to chr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date` class describes a particular day. (BTW, the internal representation is the *number* of days since 1970-01-01.) So, you can‘t have a `Date` without specifying a day.

If you want to keep the `Date` class when denoting a particular month you can round down to the *first day of the month*:

```
lubridate::floor_date(as.Date("2019-04-19"), "month")
```

which will return `2019-04-01`.

With OP's data:

```
df <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(c("2002-01-24", "2003-02-25", "2004-03-26")))
df$Month <- lubridate::floor_date((df$Date), "month")
df
```

> ```
>         Date      Month
> 1 2002-01-24 2002-01-01
> 2 2003-02-25 2003-02-01
> 3 2004-03-26 2004-03-01
> ```

```
str(df)
```

> ```
> 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  2 variables:
>  $ Date : Date, format: "2002-01-24" "2003-02-25" "2004-03-26"
>  $ Month: Date, format: "2002-01-01" "2003-02-01" "2004-03-01"
> ```

This is very handy for plotting monthly aggregates.